# Spring MVC: how secure access to static content with authorization check

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm currently working on a Spring-MVC web application in which the users can upload files to the server. Those files are saved in the server-side file system and served as static content: my application is deployed on a Tomcat instance and I've added a context in the *server.xml* file to make them accessible.

Now, I want to secure the access to those files. Basically, a user should only be allowed to access the files he/she uploaded.

What would be the best way to implement this authorization check?

Comment: How can you determine which user uploaded a file?

Comment: Associate the File table with person, use many-to-one association. Save in the table information like where is the file saved on disk. Now when the user logs in, you can search by the users id in the filetable for which files the user has. If thats not what you want, let me know, I will remove my comment.

Comment: Also, you can perform authorization at controller side using atPreAuthorize annotation for roles and service and dao with atSecured annotation for roles.

Comment: @HankLapidez: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have a DB table in which I store each uploaded file's name and location on the file system, and its owner as well.

Comment: @WeareBorg: That's the solution I was thinking about but I was wondering if there was another solution that does not imply implementing authorization check at controller level. Given that those files are served statically, I would like to avoid having to add some code at controller level.

Comment: If you want to add business logic to check which user downloads which file, then logic per say has to be implemented in your project. I just don't understand what is the problem with adding authorization check at controller and/or service layer. That's the whole purpose of it.

Comment: I don't have any problem with that. Just wondering it there was another way to get to the same result...

Comment: As far as I know there is none, do you want me to construct an answer out of my comment which you can accept. When replying to comments, please use @ symbol and then my stackoverflow name, so I am notified when you have replied.